# Update rows in a MySQL table with given key

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to update some rows in a table by given `user_id`. I am using Node.js, React.js and PHPMyAdmin MySQL database. This is my table: https://ibb.co/zXVg0Mx (as you see there are several different user_id's) My new `(params)` looks like this:

```
[
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'alternative hypothesis',
      p_rate: 0,
      s_rate: 6,
      user_id: 33
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'applied research',
      p_rate: 0,
      s_rate: 6,
      user_id: 33
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: 'basic research',
      p_rate: 0,
      s_rate: 3,
      user_id: 33
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: 'best available evidence',
      p_rate: 0,
      s_rate: 10,
      user_id: 33
    }
  ]
}
```

Basically only `s_rate` value changes. What I want to do, is to update all rows with given `user_id` with new value of `s_rate`.

My function is this, for some reason it gives

```
Result =>  <ref *2> ServerResponse {
  _events: [Object: null prototype] { finish: [Function: bound resOnFinish] },
```

and not updating values.

Function:

```
app.post('/saveTable', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err

        const params = req.body

        connection.query('UPDATE words SET s_rate = ? WHERE user_id = ?',
            [params.s_rate, params.user_id],
            (err, rows) => {
                connection.release()
                if (!err) {
                    console.log('Result => ', res)
                } else {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
    })
})
```

Comment: What is the mysql package ? mysql2 ?

Comment: @Alaindeseine yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what I was trying to do is to update the whole table.
According to this answer: [MySQL: Is there a way to update an entire table in one query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003200/mysql-is-there-a-way-to-update-an-entire-table-in-one-query)
there is **no way to implement a full table update**. Basically I had to put a save button near to each row in my table (on front-end design) and call the API according to that. In case anyone faces the same problem this is how I call the API in Node.js for **each row**:

```
app.post('/saveTable', (req, res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
        if (err) throw err

        const params = req.body

        connection.query('UPDATE words SET ? WHERE id = ?',
            [params.updatedRow, params.updatedRow.id],
            (err, rows) => {
                connection.release()
                if (!err) {
                    res.send(`Table has been updated.`)
                } else {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            })
    })
})
```